# Keep Bootstrap Tooltip visible if you mouse onto the tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

So I have an element in which I have a Bootstrap tooltip working on hover.  However if the user moves the mouse onto the tooltip I want to keep the tooltip open.  Currently by the time the user moves the mouse onto the space occupied by the tooltip the tooltip has closed.  The tooltip will include html including a couple buttons.

Any thoughts on how I can keep it open if the user moves from the element that caused the hover to the tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger it manually with jQuery:

```
$('.myTooltip') .tooltip({trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');
```

Here is the markup and a demo,

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" class="myTooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.myTooltip').tooltip({trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/RWBgXa)